# Rendering MathML on svg using d3.js

Tags: svg, d3.js, mathml

I am trying to render MathML equations on svg using d3.js. Can anyone help me getting a quadratic equation on svg. I tried doing it using foreign object with no success.

Comment: Can you show us some code you tried to implement ?

Comment: I started with a sample. The code is at
http://jsfiddle.net/p3wuu2pw/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<del>I spent quite some time trying to make it work in a JSFiddle with no success, but it works great on my PC.</del>  JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p3wuu2pw/7/). Do you mind trying the following and let me know if it works with you too?

Step 1. Load MathJax

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

Step 2. Use this code to append a foreignObject

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",400).attr("height",400)
var text = svg.append("foreignObject").attr("width",100).attr("height",100)
text.text("$$ x = \\sum_{i \\in A} i^{2} $$")
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
```

However, if you still prefer MathML, then you can use the following:

```
text.html("<math display=\"block\"><mrow><mi>x</mi><mo>=</mo><mfrac><mrow><mo>−</mo><mi>b</mi><mo>±</mo><msqrt><mrow><msup><mi>b</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>−</mo><mn>4</mn><mi>a</mi><mi>c</mi></mrow></msqrt></mrow><mrow><mn>2</mn><mi>a</mi></mrow></mfrac></mrow></math>")
```

I know I am adding more scripts for you to load, but my understanding is that MathML is not really much used any more.

I hope it helps.

**EDIT**
Finally a JSFiddle here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/p3wuu2pw/7/)

Thanks

Comment: This is good but we have the input as proper MathML which needs to be rendered on SVG

Comment: No problem. I think that the rendering of MathML using MathJax is better though. Also, I am not sure that MathML is really supported any more. Chrome is not displying it (as @RobertLongson mentions)

Comment: Again the same question. Is it possible to convert MathML to MathJax syntax.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 3):

You've two bugs

- foreignObject must have width/height attributes
- mathml elements must be created in the mathml namespace

Fixing these results in this...

```
d3.ns.prefix.mathml = "http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML";

var foreignObject = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
var x = foreignObject.append("foreignObject")
    .attr("requiredExtensions", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")
    .attr("width", "100")
    .attr("height", "100")
var text = x.append("mathml:mo")
var row = x.append("mathml:mrow")
row.append("mathml:mi").text("a")
row.append("mathml:mo").text('\u2062')
var msup = row.append("msup")
msup.append("mathml:mi").text("x")
msup.append("mathml:mi").text("2")
row.append("mathml:mo").text("+")
row.append("mathml:mi").text("b")
row.append("mathml:mo").text('\u2062')
row.append("mathml:mi").text('x')
row.append("mathml:mo").text('+')
row.append("mathml:mi").text('c')
```

[or as a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/p3wuu2pw//)

Comment: I tried for ax square + bx + c. But again no success
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p3wuu2pw/3/

Comment: Thanks for your effort. This is strange. Its not working in Chrome. Is there any thing i am missing?

Comment: Is it that Chrome doesnot support MathML on SVG or it doesn't support MathML at all

Comment: The latter. No mathml at all.

Comment: Ouch. Need to find another solution for the same. Is it possible to convert MathML to MathJax and then load it. The other solution given above works on chrome. So just thinking out loud id MathML could be converted to MathJax syntax

Comment: You don't need to convert it. MathJax can render MathML.